# why node express send different headers after the first request

Tags: node.js, express

I got a route like this

```js
router.post('/scan', async (request, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Custom-Title', 'Done')
    res.setHeader('Custom-Message', 'Good')
    res.setHeader('Custom-Time', '500')
    res.send('ok')
})
```

In the first request I got response headers like this

[image]

With same request and the same body data, in the second request. I got response headers like this

[image]

As you can see, they both different, why I'm getting different response headers ? I want to have the headers like in the first request. Everytime.

Comment: thats' all there is to it. It's the full code

Comment: that's the body of request. the request send json `{"content": "772233"}`. the reponse just simple say 'ok'

Comment: Have you tried testing this using a simpler tool, such as `curl` or `httpie`, or even `netcat` from a command-line? Just to verify the problem is actually on the server and not on this report